# F# explicit match vs function syntax

Tags: syntax, f#

Sorry about the vague title, but part of this question is what these two syntax styles are called:

```
let foo1 x = 
    match x with
    | 1 -> "one"
    | _ -> "not one"

let foo2 = function 
    | 1 -> "one" 
    | _ -> "not one"
```

The other part is what difference there is between the two, and when I would want to use one or the other?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The match version is called a "pattern matching expression".  The function version is called a "pattern matching function".  Found in section 6.6.4 of the [spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc245030840).

Using one over the other is a matter of style.  I prefer only using the function version when I need to define a function that is only a match statement.

Comment: Thank you. Although Functional Programming Using F# says the use of the function keyword indicates it is a pattern matching function, this answer and the OP clarify a brain stuck moment.

Comment: The link appears to be broken.

Comment: updated link --> section 6.5.5 of https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf

Answer (score 90):

The pro for the second syntax is that when used in a lambda, it could be a bit more terse and readable.

```
List.map (fun x -> match x with | 1 -> "one" | _ -> "not one") [0;1;2;3;1]
```

vs

```
List.map (function 1 -> "one" | _ -> "not one") [0;1;2;3;1]
```

Answer (score 26):

The function version is a short hand for the full match syntax in the special case where the match statement is the entire function and the function only has a single argument (tuples count as one).  If you want to have two arguments then you need to use the full match syntax*.  You can see this in the types of the following two functions.

```
//val match_test : string -> string -> string
let match_test x y = match x, y with
                        | "A", _ -> "Hello A"
                        | _, "B" -> "Hello B"
                        | _ -> "Hello ??"

//val function_test : string * string -> string                   
let function_test = function
                        | "A", _ -> "Hello A"
                        | _, "B" -> "Hello B"
                        | _ -> "Hello ??"
```

As you can see match version takes two separate arguments whereas the function version takes a single tupled argument.  I use the function version for most single argument functions since I find the function syntax looks cleaner.

*If you really wanted to you can get the function version to have the right type signature but it looks pretty ugly in my opinion - see example below.

```
//val function_match_equivalent : string -> string -> string
let function_match_equivalent x y = (x, y) |> function
                                                | "A", _ -> "Hello A"
                                                | _, "B" -> "Hello B"
                                                | _ -> "Hello ??"
```

Answer (score 13):

They do the same thing in your case -- the `function` keyword acts like a combination of the `fun` keyword (to produce an anonymous lambda) followed by the `match` keyword.

So technically these two are the same, with the addition of a `fun`:

```
let foo1 = fun x ->
    match x with
    | 1 -> "one"
    | _ -> "not one"

let foo2 = function
    | 1 -> "one"
    | _ -> "not one"
```

Comment: Isn't it actually the other way around - i.e. `fun` is technically defined in terms of `function | _ -> ...`?

Comment: To be specific, `fun x y -> ...` would be `fun x -> fun y -> ...`, and then `fun x -> ...` would be `function | x -> ...`. It's why you can do pattern matching in `fun` - e.g. `fun (x::xs) -> ...`.

Answer (score 11):

Just for completeness sake, I just got to page 321 of [Expert FSharp](http://www.apress.com/book/view/1590598504):

> "Note, Listing 12-2 uses the expression form `function pattern-rules -> expression`. This is equivalent to `(fun x -> match x with pattern-rules -> expression)` and is especially convenient as a way to define functions working directly over discriminated unions."

Answer (score 7):

**function** only allows for one argument but allows for pattern matching, while **fun** is the more general and flexible way to define a function. Take a look here: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html

Comment: why do you say only 1 argument instead of only the last argument? it's possible to have more than 1 argument and use "function". is this a higher order function interpretation?

Answer (score 4):

The two syntaxes are equivalent. Most programmers choose one or the other and then use it consistently.

The first syntax remains more readable when the function accepts several arguments before starting to work.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but I will throw my $0.02.

In general I like better the `match` version since I come from the Python world where "explicit is better than implicit."

Of course if type information on the parameter is needed the `function` version cannot be used.

OTOH I like the argument made by `Stringer` so I will start to use `function` in simple lambdas.