# When to use 'function' instead of 'fun'?

Tags: f#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [F# explicit match vs function syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839016/f-explicit-match-vs-function-syntax)

Hello,

I am learning F# and am confused by 'fun' and 'function' keywords. My understanding is that these are sort of the same thing.

```
// Use 'fun'
let testFunction1 = fun argument -> match argument with
                                    | Some(x) -> x
                                    | None    -> 0

// Use 'function'
let testFunction2 = function
                    | Some(x) -> x
                    | None    -> 0
```

Is 'function' just shorthand for "fun x -> match x with"? Is there any runtime / optimization difference between the two?  Why would I prefer to use one over the other?

As it stands, 'function' just seems to make code harder to read. Am I missing something?

Comment: If it looks fun, don't use function; it kills the fun.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839016/f-explicit-match-vs-function-syntax

Comment: Sorry for the dupe question! I didn't see the other one.

Comment: This is not a dupe. Other question asked about `match` vs `function`. This is asking about `fun` vs `function`.

Comment: Your use of `function` in the example is incorrect: instead of `function argument with` (and a match expression), it should just be `function` (and a match expression). I'll edit your question to be correct, for the sake of anyone else who might stumble across it in the future (as I just did).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply syntactic sugar. Just like in C# `c => c = 'A'` is syntax sugar for `delegate (char c) { return c = 'A'; }`. It all comes down to personal preference really.

Answer (score 13):

**function** only allows for one argument but allows for pattern matching, while **fun** is the more general and flexible way to define a function. Take a look here: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html

Comment: On the other hand, you can have multiple clauses separated by `|` when you use `function`.

Comment: function allows pattern matching, but only on the last argument*