# Printfn list error "('a list -> 'b list) not compatible"

Tags: f#

So I'm getting the following error message:

```
The type '('a list -> 'b list)' is not compatible with any of the types
byte,int16,int32,int64,sbyte,uint16,uint32,uint64,nativeint,unativeint, 
arising from the use of a printf-style format string
```

And this is the code that sets it off:

```
let rec multC c = function
  | [] -> []
  | head::tail -> c * head::multC c tail


let p1 = [1; 2; 3];;
let resMultC = multC p1
printfn "resMultC: %d" resMultC
```

I can't for the love of me figure out why it won't print it, which I assume is what the error means. Any hints?

Comment: `multC` takes two arguments, you've only supplied one. Maybe [F# explicit match vs function syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1839016/636019) will clarify...

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand something but I'm not quite sure what I'm supposed to get from the link you provided.

Comment: `function` does more than you probably think it does – in particular, it acts as an argument, making your function binary, not unary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check `multC` signature in FSI it's `c:int -> _arg1:int list -> int list`. That means it takes two arguments (one is explicitly declared as `c`, the other one implicitly from the `function` declaration).

That said the problem with your code is that you are providing only one argument

```
let resMultC = multC p1
```

instead of two

```
let resMultC = multC 2 p1 // [2; 4; 6]
```

But even now the last call wan't compile as you are trying to print a list using the int formatter (`%d`). Use `%A` instead for F#-specific types:

```
printfn "resMultC: %A" resMultC // resMultC: [2; 4; 6]
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for the help. Using FSI to check is a great trick.