# How does the compiler treat a boolean argument that has been partially applied?

Tags: if-statement, f#, boolean

I read an interesting article about `boolean` arguments of functions:

https://medium.com/compileswift/clean-code-the-curse-of-a-boolean-parameter-c237a830b7a3

The author argues that in many cases it is better to split a function that has a `boolean` argument into two. This is because the use of boolean parameters increases the `cyclomatic complexity` of the code.

So consider the following simple function:

```
let fbool (b: bool) (x: int) =
    if b then x
    else -x
```

Next, define a function defined from partial application, as follows:

```
let ftrue x = fbool true x
```

or equivalently

```
let ftrue = fbool true
```

Is the F# compiler smart enough to do what the author recommends, that is, is `ftrue` as defined above a function that does not contain an `if` statement and therefore does not contribute to cyclomatic complexity? Or does it contain an `if` statement but happens to always choose the `true` branch?

Comment: Don't treat cyclomatic complexity religiously! It is only a measure invented to quantify one property of code that people associate with its complexity (namely, the amount of branching by means of flow control constructs such as if-then-else or match). If there's real complexity in the logic that you're modelling, it will need to surface somehow in your code anyway.

Comment: @scrwtp - Suppose I have a quite complex function with many lines of code. Somewhere there is an `if` statement. Suppose I have two entirely separate projects, one using the `true` version, the other the `false version`

Comment: @scrwtp - Suppose I have a quite complex function with many lines of code. Somewhere there is an `if` statement. Suppose I have two entirely separate projects, one using the `true` version, the other the `false` version. In neither project there is complexity associated to the boolean. I could avoid the code duplication involved in writing two different function by using partial application as above. If later I find a better way to implement the function the two versions are simultaneously updated. This reasoning applies to partial application in general, not only when the parameter is boolean

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete comment above. The 5 minute limit got me.

Comment: I get the crux of your question (i.e. whether compiler makes an attempt to optimize things). The thing is, the intent behind CC is how it pertains to code-as-written, not code-as-compiled. You're not avoiding complexity in code-as-written that way - if anything, you make things more complex by introducing more functions in your API.

Comment: That would also be my criticism of the article you link to - "optimizing" for one particular measure means you make sacrifices elsewhere. Writing clean code is a balancing act. Let's leave it at that, I don't want to derail a good question with general musings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The F# compiler isn't smart enough to eliminate branches like this. In general the compilers in .NET apply only few optimizations in the hope that the jitter will optimize for them.

If you made the `fbool` function inline `ftrue` ends up like this:

```
public static int ftrue(int v)
{
    bool flag = true;
    if (flag)
    {
        return v;
    }
    return -v;
}
```

Here the compiler "obviously" should eliminate the branches but it doesn't.

However, you might be lucky and the code complexity tools realizes that one of the branches will never be taken and don't add this test to the CC score.

Comment: Thanks. The code (C#?) makes it clear. But I don‘t know what is jitter and what are the code complexity tools.

Comment: Jitter transform il code (machine code for a fictive cpu) to machine code that the cpu can execute. This is done when the program starts. Code Complexity tools measure things like cyclomatic complexity. An example is ndepend

Answer (score 3):

The article's author is really talking about how understandable the code is - the interaction **between the programmer and the source code**. This is almost always what is being considered when people talk about cyclomatic complexity. This has nothing to do with the output of the compiler.

The way the source code relates to what is run on the machine is a different matter. And although branch elimination can improve performance, it doesn't remove branching from the code and therefore the programmer still deals with the cyclomatic complexity.

Partially applying a function as you describe is a good way to make the intent of the function clearer at the point of use. Instead of passing what is likely to be meaningless true/false value, you have two functions with **meaningful** names instead. This only helps if the names are more meaningful than true/false, which they aren't in your toy example.

However, this partial application does not reduce cyclomatic complexity at all, since the source code still has exactly the same amount of branching.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure F#'s partial application is done in the most straightforward way possible, i.e. not rewriting the function. To have `fbool true` turn into a function that simply returns `x` without the `if` statement, and `fbool false` turn into a function that returns `-x`, would 
require more compiler code than it's worth. And you'd only gain a benefit on trivial examples like this one, that really should be split into two functions anyway.

Well, maybe there's one other place where you'd benefit: a function that's a single `match` expression, like:

```
let f optValue secondParam =
    match optValue with
    | None -> printfn "No optional param. Second parameter %A" secondParam
    | Some x -> printfn "Got an x value of %A, and 2nd param is %A" x secondParam
```

In this case, `f None` could theoretically be turned into a simple `printfn` call (though I don't think the compiler would do it), and `f (Some 3)` would turn into a different `printfn` call.

However, even that example is contrived and not likely to be worth writing, because in most functions where you're just doing a `match` on a single parameter, you put that parameter *last* (and maybe use [the `function` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839016/f-explicit-match-vs-function-syntax)). E.g., in real code my example above would probably have looked like:

```
let f param = function
    | None -> printfn "No optional param. Required parameter is %A" param
    | Some x -> printfn "Got an x value of %A, and required param is %A" x param
```

In which case partial application won't cause the function to be rewritten, because by the time you've applied the parameter that's being used in the `match` expresson, you've applied the last parameter so you're actually calling the function.

So because real-world code would hardly ever benefit enough from this to be worth the immense complexity of adding that compiler feature (if there's other code before the `if` statement, it's probably non-trivial to duplicate it into two functions), I'm pretty sure the F# compiler does not do the kind of rewriting you mention.

**NOTE:** I have not been able to turn up any information on this in a quick Google search, so it's possible this answer is incorrect; if so, please downvote and/or comment to inform me and I'll edit it to incorporate the *correct* information.